# C++ copy constructor for a class with an array attribute

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

I am creating a matrix template and ran into a problem writing the copy constructor. While data appears to be copied correctly from within the constructor, the object returned to the main program does not have the correct values (looks like its pointing to a different memory address). In my attempts to debug this I tried creating a minimalist example, though strangely this did not produce the same error. I get the sense that this issue is either beyond my understanding of C++ ...or caused by a typo I've somehow missed. Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

**matlib.h**

```
#ifndef MATLIB_H
#define MATLIB_H
#include <iostream>

    namespace matlib{
        template <typename T>
        struct Matrix {
                unsigned int rows;   //number of rows
                unsigned int cols;   //number of columns
                unsigned int length; //number of elements
                T data[];                  //contents of matrix
    
                /* Constructors */
                Matrix(unsigned int m, unsigned int n) : rows(m), cols(n) {
                    length = m*n;
                    T data[m*n];
                    //::std::cout << "Hello from the null constructor!" << ::std::endl;
                    //::std::cout << "rows = " << rows << ", cols = " << cols << ", length = " << length << ::std::endl;
                }
                
                Matrix(const Matrix<T> &mat) {
                    rows = mat.rows;
                    cols = mat.cols;
                    length = mat.length;
                    T data[mat.length];
                    ::std::cout << "Hello from the copy constructor!" << ::std::endl;                
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                        data[i] = mat.data[i];
                        ::std::cout << "data[" << i << "] = " << data[i] << ", mat.data[" << i << "] = " << mat.data[i] << ::std::endl;
                    }
                } 
    
                //Single element indexing and assigment
                T& operator() (int i, int j) {
                    return data[ i*this->cols + j ];
                }
    
                T& operator() (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
                    return data[ i*this->cols + j ];
                }
    
                //Single element indexing and assigment
                T& operator() (int i) {
                    return data[i];
                }
    
                T& operator() (unsigned int i) {
                    return data[i];
                } 
    
                
        };
    
    }
    
    #endif
```

**testscript.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matlib.h"

int main() {
    float arr[7] = {4, 1, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2};
    matlib::Matrix<float> mat1(1,7);

    //Assign values and print
    std::cout << "mat1 = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < mat1.length; ++i) {
        mat1(i) = arr[i];
        std::cout << mat1(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;

    //Copy the object
    matlib::Matrix<float> mat2 = mat1;

    //Print the copied values
    std::cout << "mat2 = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < mat2.length; ++i) {
        std::cout << mat2(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Console output:**

```
mat1 = 4 1 6 6 8 4 2 

Hello from the copy constructor!
data[0] = 4, mat.data[0] = 4
data[1] = 1, mat.data[1] = 1
data[2] = 6, mat.data[2] = 6
data[3] = 6, mat.data[3] = 6
data[4] = 8, mat.data[4] = 8
data[5] = 4, mat.data[5] = 4
data[6] = 2, mat.data[6] = 2
mat2 = 9.80909e-45 1.4013e-45 9.80909e-45 9.80909e-45 4 1 6
```

I'm sure many people will suggest solutions involving 'std::vector' though this is mostly a learning exercise with HPC in mind. I will likely add bound checking once this is a bit more developed.

Comment: You never assign anything to `Matrix::data`. You only declare a bunch of local variables with the same name.

Comment: Unsized array members like `T data[]` are not standard C++, and nor is initializing it from runtime values like `T data[m*n];` -- that's variable-length-arrays, and are a non-standard extension given by the compiler. If you're using features like this, then you aren't writing normal/standard C++ to begin with

Comment: Would I need to allocate space in the constructor? Something like: `data = new T[m*n];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Version:** Just use `std::vector`. It will will make your life easier, and has far less pitfalls than a manual approach.

---

**Long Version:** You have two major problems in your code:

1. You are using Flexible-Arrays incorrectly (and this is a compiler extension, not standard C++), and
2. You are using Variable-Length Arrays incorrectly (and this is also a compiler extension, not standard C++)

### 1. Flexible Array Members

The first compiler-extension you use is a feature from [c](/questions/tagged/c) called **flexible arrays**:

```cpp
struct Matrix {
    ...
    T data[];
 // ^~~~~~~~~
```

[c](/questions/tagged/c) allows using arrays of unsized data at the end of a `struct` to denote objects that may be given dynamic sizes at runtime when allocated by `malloc`. This is not, however, valid standard [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and it is ill-advised to be using this since it does not fit into C++'s allocator model at all.

This should be changed out for something more coherent.

### 2. Variable Length Arrays

The second extension you are using is also from [c](/questions/tagged/c), called **variable-length arrays**:

```cpp
Matrix(unsigned int m, unsigned int n) : rows(m), cols(n) {
    ...
    T data[m*n];
```

This is also not valid standard C++. You cannot construct an array from runtime values in C++ -- **full stop**. Arrays are known at compile-time, and only at compile-time.

Additionally, and this is where you are experiencing the problem, `T data[m*n]` is creating a **new** VLA named `data` that **shadows** the flexible array also named `data`. So each function you define `T data[m*n]` or `T data[other.length]`, you are actually creating **new** arrays, writing to them, and then doing nothing with them. This is why you are seeing different addresses.

### Suggested Fixes

1. Use heap memory, perhaps with `std::unique_ptr` to manage things for you. Allocate the size on construction, clone it on copy.

   ```cpp
   // Construction
   Matrix(unsigned int m, unsigned int n) : rows(m), cols(n), data(std::make_unique<T[]>(m * n))
   // where 'data' is std::unique_ptr<T[]>
   { ... }
   ```

   This will then require a custom copy constructor:

   ```cpp
   Matrix(const Matrix& other) : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols), data(std::make_unique<T[]>(rows * cols)){
       // Copy all elements from 'other' to 'data'
       std::copy_n(other.get(), rows * cols, data.get());
   }
   ```

   Or, better yet:
2. Use `std::vector`. It already knows how to do lifetime and saves you from a number of pitfalls. If you already know the max size of the `vector`, you can just use `resize` or `reserve`+`push_back` and this saves reallocation costs.

   ```cpp
   Matrix(unsigned int m, unsigned int n) : rows(m), cols(n), data(m * n)     
   // where 'data' is std::vector<T>
   { ... }
   ```

   Using `std::vector` you can just do:

   ```cpp
   Matrix(const Matrix& other) = default;
   ```

   in your class declaration, and it will use `std::vector`'s underlying copy constructor. This is a far better approach IMO.

---

### A separate note on "High-Performance Computing"

I encourage you to **not** shy away from containers like `std::vector` purely for the purpose of HPC.

To be blunt, developers are notoriously bad at determining what is, and is not, good for performance. The underlying hardware plays the biggest role with factors like speculative execution, branch prediction, instruction pipelining, and cache locality. Heap memory and a few extra byte-copies are usually the least of your worries unless you are repeatedly growing the container in a very tight loop.

On the contrary, heap memory is easy to move around (e.g. move constructors), since it's a pointer-copy, whereas buffer storage would be copied in totality even for moves. Additionally, [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) introduces polymorphic allocators with different options where memory resources come from -- allowing for far faster allocation options (e.g. a virtual memory resource that allocates full pages for `std::vector`).

Even where performance matters: Try a solution and **profile** before trying to optimize it. Don't waste effort up front, because the results may surprise you. Sometimes doing [**more work** can result in **faster code**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJJTYQYB1JQ) in the right conditions.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Thank you for the detailed explanation and multiple suggestions. As a new C++ user, this tells me a lot more about how the code is being interpreted rather than sweeping it under the rug of `std::vector`, even if it is the better approach.

Comment: @StillUsesFORTRAN Happy to help. Though i am a little puzzled why I was selected for the correct answer before having it changed for some reason. Manually managing memory is **not** a good or sustainable suggestion for 99% of developers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I could only 'accept' one answer. Both were very helpful in understanding what is happening in memory, which I'd like to be very aware of as I become more comfortable with the language.

Comment: Quick followup: is `std::vector` not allocated in heap memory?

Comment: @StillUsesFORTRAN `std::vector` is in heap memory (same with `new` or `make_unique`). However for constructing matrices with sizes given at runtime (via parameters), this is the **only** standard way to do this in C++. There doesn't exist any (standard) utility for doing this in any other way.

Comment: Even for high-performance computing, heap usage isn't necessary something to shy away from. To be blunt, Developers have notoriously bad intuition as to what is "high-performance", and where performance even matters. Speculative execution, cache locality, and branch prediction play bigger roles than the cost of heap allocations in almost all cases. If performance ever matters, profile -- then make a decision. The results may surprise you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving your dynamic (de)allocation code in specific protected methods. It will help you avoid memory leaks, double free, useless reallocations and keep your constructors more readable.

```
template <typename T>
struct Matrix {
    std::size_t rows{0}, cols{0};
    size_t capacity{0};
    T* data{nullptr};
    
    Matrix() = default;
    Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols): Matrix()
    {
        this->allocate(rows * cols);
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
    }
    
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& other): Matrix()
    {
        *this = other;
    }
    
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix<T>& other) 
    {
        if (this != &other) {
            this->allocate(other.length());
            std::copy_n(other.data, other.length(), data);
            this->rows = other.rows;
            this->cols = other.cols;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    ~Matrix()
    {
        this->release();
    }
    
    size_t length() const { return rows * cols; }

    // Access
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) { /*TODO*/ }
    const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const { /*TODO*/ }
    
protected:
    void allocate(size_t reqLength) 
    {
        if (data && capacity >= reqLength) return;
        this->release();
        data = new T [reqLength];
        capacity = reqLength;
    }
    
    void release()
    {
        if (data) delete [] data;
        data = nullptr;
        capacity = 0;
    }    
};
```

Comment: [tag:c++11] has been out for 10 years, longer if you count TR1. It's highly advisable to use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` rather than suggesting raw `new`/`delete` at any point in the code. Manually managing memory is extremely error-prone. Small changes may introduce potential exception-states that can lead to leaks, and it's just not worth it over using smart pointers which are 0-overhead -- or better yet, `std::vector` which manages this all for you

Comment: Totally agree. That being said, OP wanted something without `std::vector` (or similar STL stuff, I presumed).